# Factoring $m^4+2m^3-m^2-2m-8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> Factorize $$m^4+2m^3-m^2-2m-8$$

First I plugged numbers like $m=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$ in the expression and neither of them is a root so I can't use rational roots theorem here to find a factor. I've also tried writing it as $$m^4+2m^3-m^2-2m-8=(m^2+am+b)(m^2+cm+d)$$ And expanding it gives,

$$ \begin{cases} {a+c=2} \\ {b+d+ac=-1} \\ {ad+bc=-2} \\ {bd=-8} \end{cases}  $$  Then I used $a=2-c$ and changed it to three equations but still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Why would $3$ be a root? You seem to have some misunderstanding about the rational root theorem

Comment: @NinadMunshi You are right $3$ is obviously not a root. In fact I meant I tried small integers.

Comment: Let continue your approach: $a+c=2 \Rightarrow a=1-t, c=1+t$. $b+d+ac=-1 \Rightarrow b+d=-1-(1-t)(1+t)=t^2-2 \Rightarrow$ $b=\frac{t^2-2}2+u, d=\frac{t^2-2}2-u$. $ad+bc=\frac12 ((a+c)(d+b)+(a-c)(d-b)=$ $\frac12 (2(t^2-2)+2t(-2u))=t^2-2tu-2=-2$ $\Rightarrow t^2-2tu=0 \Rightarrow t=0 \lor t=2u$. $bd=\left(\frac{t^2-2}2\right)^2-u^2=-8$. $t=0 \Rightarrow u^2=9 \Rightarrow^* u=3$. $a=c=1$, $b=2$, $d=-4$.

Comment: Another approach: $m^4+2m^3-m^2-2m-8=$ $m^4+2m^3+m^2-2m^2-2m-8=$ $(m^2+m)^2-2(m^2+m)-8$. $m^2+m=t$. $t^2-2t-8$ can be factorized easily.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thanks a lot for the help! I think it is a good idea if you write your comments as answer so that I can mark as accepted one.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I have a questuon about your first comment: Is this a known approach to solve such system of equations and has a name or you found it by experience?

Comment: I've seen this approach not long ago as way of solving quadratic equations with Vietas theorem. $x^2+2mx+n=0$, $x_1+x_2=2m$, $x_1=m+y$, $x_2=m-y$, $x_1x_2=m^2-y^2=n$, $y^2=m^2-n$, $y=\sqrt{m^2-n}$. There is no new roots at using $y=-\sqrt{m^2-n}$, because we have both $m+y$ and $m-y$ as roots.